# Is it possible to create the arc shadow in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying give a Cordova app native feel by mimicking the native ui. It's mostly successful, from status bar color to even the ripple effect (thanks to the paper elements!) However there's one thing that I can't seem to know how to achieve, the no-more-scrolling-for-you shadow:

[image]

<sup>(screenshot of Samsung's built in dictionary)</sup>

Is there any way to achieve this effect on Android? Or is there any way to "enable" this effect in the in-app browser? Without that the app still feels webapp-ish.

The only way I can think of to make it sort of work is to draw it with a canvas, but that's just not practical at all.

Comment: You could try to use Google Polymer.

Comment: @ChristophBühler If you have read my question you would know I'm already using Polymer.

Comment: I did read your question. It does not say anything about Polymer. Just putting it in the tags is lazy. Good luck with your mood.